# Xcode build automation scheduled integration bot setting

Tags: xcode, git, build, bots, schedule

I have checked bot schedule for manually,periodically and poll for new commit(it works in 5 min) all are three option working properly, but I am unable to understand fourth option "On commit using custom trigger script".

Please any one can explain this how does this fourth option work? will it work for immediate integration on each commit.

Please Check below link also:
http://www.likelyanswer.com/30202671/How-Do-I-Create-A-Trigger-Script-For-Bot-On-Xcode-5-Ci%3F
[image: enter image descri![enter image description here]ption here][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J4ppU.png)

Comment: Where is this UI found?

Comment: You find this UI in the Xcode bots’ web interface. Indeed this option is not available directly in Xcode.

Answer (score 7):

This is based on my own investigation and may be completely wrong in future releases.

The Xcode service exposes an HTTP endpoint to perform an immediate integration when the trigger script schedule option is selected:

> **POST /xcs/kick-commit-bots**
>
> Parameters:
>
> **repository:** URL to the repository as shown in the bot's settings.
>
> **branch:** (optional) Name of the branch to trigger integrations for. If specified, only bots configured to build this branch will be integrated. If unspecified, all bots for the specified repository will be integrated.

Example:

```
curl http://server.local/xcs/kick-commit-bots \
 -d repository=ssh://server.local/git/example.git \
 -d branch=master
```

To make use of trigger script scheduling option you'll need to create a repository hook to trigger this endpoint on receipt of new commits. OS X Server contains an example hook in `/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/share/collabd/server/ruby/kick_build_bot.rb`. For hosted Git repositories created through the Xcode service a post-receive hook using this script is created for you automatically.

Note that the repository URL sent to `/xcs/kick-commit-bots` must match the repository URL as shown in the bot's settings in the web interface. It seems that for hosted repositories the URL can change - sometimes an `ssh:` URL is used and sometimes a `file:` URL is used.